# Compare each and every items of two arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

I do have two arrays:

`int[] oddArr = { 11, 9, ... };`

`int[] evenArr = {4, 2, 8, ... };`

I want to check if every items from **oddArr** is greater than every items from **evenArr** then we should do some logic.

Like: 
`if(11 > 4 && 11 > 2 && 11 > 8 && 9 > 4 && 9 > 2 && 9 > 8 && ...)`

I tried something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < oddArr.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < evenArr.Length; j++)
    {
        if (oddArr[i] > evenArr[j])
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then what is your question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would think about the problem differently - for everything in `oddArr` to be greater than everything in `evenArr`, then the *minimum* of `oddArr` has to be greater than the *maximum* of `evenArr`:

```
if (oddArr.Min() > evenArr.Max())
```

(You'll need a `using` directive for `System.Linq` to bring in the `Min` and `max` extension methods.)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `Linq` library then you can do it like

```
int minOdd = oddArr[0];
for (int i = 1; i < oddArr.Length; i++)
{
    if(minOdd>oddArr[i])
        minOdd = oddArr[i];
}

int maxEven = evenArr[0]
for (int j = 0; j < evenArr.Length; j++)
{
    if (maxEven > evenArr[j])
        maxEven = evenArr[j];
}

if(minOdd>maxEven)
{
//do someting
}
```

Logically if every element of `oddArr` is greater than every element of `evenArr` then minimum number of `oddArr` would be greater than maximum number of `evenArr`.

Answer (score 1):

While Jon Skeet's answer is the better solution here you can still compare every item from `oddArr` to every item from `evenArr` using LINQ. Here's how:

```
var result = oddArr.All(oddItem => evenArr.All(evenItem => evenItem < oddItem));

if(result){
    // every item from oddArr > every item from evenArr
    // Do something
}
```